# Page not found error and login page disappears again and again in FBconnect project Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, fbconnect

In Facebook API...FBConnect...I have used API Key and App Secret...but when I login to the Facebook Page two kind of confusing situations are happening..

1) when I press buttion login screen are coming but It disappears after entering details..then again I have to press the button for getting the Facebook Page back and again it disappears..

2) After login the main screen of posting is not coming...in place of that..."The page you have requested is not found such an error is coming"...what to do now?? I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook discontinued the old SDK, which is what ShareKit uses. Apps are supposed to be using the graph API now.

Check this branch:
https://github.com/colinhumber/ShareKit

It will work with the new graph API, and you should be good to go with some minor modifications.

Big thanks to Colin Humber... give the man some love:

http://twitter.com/colinhumber

https://github.com/colinhumber

Comment: Thanks for this response, @eanticev. I plan to switch over to this version of ShareKit as soon as time allows.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug report on Facebook about this issue, which seems to have started just a day or two ago: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16766.

Also, see the issue tracker discussion on ShareKit's GitHub: https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/207.

Comment: @chris...what about this issue?? do you know about this??1) when I press buttion login screen are coming but It disappears after entering details..then again I have to press the button for getting the Facebook Page back and again it disappears..i mean i want to see my home page after login which i am unable to see :( ..I am using sharekit

Comment: This issue has disappeared for me. Seems as though Facebook changed back whatever dialog they had updated earlier in the week. Of course, @eanticev is correct: all apps need to stop using the old SDK and switch to the Graph API ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue as you are. Is yours an old app or did you just recently create the app on Facebook?

Most of my new apps on facebook aren't effected by the issue. It's just my old app that I created more than a year ago.

Try searching your app on http://m.facebook.com and see if it shows up in the search results, because for some odd reason mine didn't show up on there and I believe that's the reason for the problem